# How to turn {2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_Prime -> Sqrt[x]} into {Sqrt[2],9,Sqrt[3],16,81,0.09}

Tags: list-manipulation

How to make this below work?

Input

`{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_Prime -> Sqrt[x]}`

**I wanna turn this list into**

> {Sqrt[2],9,Sqrt[3],16,81,0.09}

Comment: one option is `{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_ /; PrimeQ[x] -> Sqrt[x]}`

Comment: This is the second question of basically the same problem within half an hour. Is this homework?

What have you tried, and what problem(s) if any are you encountering? 

Questions of the "Here's what I want, do it for me" type tend to be frowned upon.

Comment: @ciao, I'm not familiar with `Head` Telling people the goal I wanna achieve will make it easier for people to find the error. By the way, what's the difference with `_x`  and `x_`?

Comment: @CarlLange why is this 1{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. `{x_PrimeQ -> Sqrt[x]}` not working?

Comment: Here's a great starting point in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html

Comment: I think the solution the author is looking for is: ```{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_?PrimeQ :> Sqrt[x]}```. Note that delayed rule ```:>```, PrimeQ (rather than Prime), and ? for the test.

Comment: @SHuisman, great work!

Comment: you can also use HoldForm  `{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_?PrimeQ -> HoldForm@Sqrt[x]}`

Comment: @Alucard, why not write in the answer below? And I thought your answer was the same as Shuisman's

Comment: rule delayed  evaluate the rhs only after applying the rule but since it has the attribute `HoldRest` it leaves it in an evaluate form.  i thought there was no need for rule delayed  and `HoldForm` would do the trick. i guess i can write it as an answer but everyone was using comments so i did the same

Comment: @kile i have realized that  you don't need HoldForm at all, as Carl Lange already proved in his comment. i think i should  delete my answer because it's wrong but i can't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_?PrimeQ -> HoldForm@Sqrt[x]}
```

update:

as Carl Lange noted there is no need  for HoldForm here because `Sqrt` leaves the square root unevaluated for prime numbers

```
   {2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_?PrimeQ -> Sqrt[x]}
```

Hovewer, if the filter was not PrimeQ but for example OddQ then it
 would have been necessary to add `HoldForm` to prevent Evaluation

```
{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. {x_?OddQ -> HoldForm@Sqrt[x]}
```